# QuerySelector is not a function

Tags: javascript

Each time I click + button on the code below, I have this error. I am completely new to JS and need your help, how to solve it out and show `totalsum` of selected items ( user input * dish price ).

```js
window.onload = function () {
  const totalPrice = calcOrder(); // calculate sum
  document.querySelector('.total-price').innerHTML = totalPrice; // put on page
}

// Calculate total sum
function calcOrder() {
  let result = 0;
  const menus = document.querySelectorAll('.single-menu');

  for (let i = 0; i < menus.length; i++) {
    const price = Number(menus.querySelector('.price').innerText);
    const qty = Number(menus.querySelector('input').value);
    result += price * qty;
  }

  return result;
}

function stepperDecrement(btn) {
  const inputEl = btn.nextElementSibling;
  const calcStep = inputEl.step - 1;
  const newValue = parseInt(inputEl.value) + calcStep;
  if (newValue >= inputEl.min && newValue <= inputEl.max) {
    inputEl.value = newValue;
  }
  const totalPrice = calcOrder(); // calculate sum
  document.querySelector('.total-price').innerHTML = totalPrice; // выводим на странице
}
function stepperIncrement(btn) {
  const inputEl = btn.previousElementSibling;
  const calcStep = inputEl.step * 1;
  const newValue = parseInt(inputEl.value) + calcStep;
  if (newValue >= inputEl.min && newValue <= inputEl.max) {
    inputEl.value = newValue;
  }
  const totalPrice = calcOrder(); // calculate sum
  document.querySelector('.total-price').innerHTML = totalPrice; // выводим на странице
}
```

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.93), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.93)),
    url("../images/saveInPhotoshop.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* MENU */
.wrapper {
  color: white;

  width: 1200px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.title h4 {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 36px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.title h4 span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.title h4:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ff7720;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.single-menu {
  flex-basis: 580px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.single-menu:nth-child(5),
.single-menu:nth-child(6) {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.single-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.single-menu:hover img {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.single-menu img {
  max-width: 180px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 3px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.single-menu h4 {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 22px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #333;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.single-menu h4 span {
  float: right;
  color: #ff7720;
  font-style: italic;
}

.filter-menu {
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 75px;
}

.filter-menu-desc {
  width: 460px;
}

.menu-description {
  width: 350px;
}

.price {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

/* Button */

.myContainer {
  width: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 45px;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

input[type="number"] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  color: #302020;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

button {
  color: #ff7720;
  background-color: #d3d2d2;
  border: none;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.decrement {
  padding: 15px 5px 15px 25px;
  border-radius: 45px 0 0 45px;
}

.increment {
  padding: 15px 25px 15px 5px;
  border-radius: 0 45px 45px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">

  <div class="single-menu">

    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    <div class="menu-content">
      <h4>Dish number three<span class="price">15.00</span></h4>
      <p class="mb-0 text-color:red">DRINKS</p>
      <p class="menu-description">Description</p>
      <div class="myContainer m-1">
        <button class="decrement" type="button" onclick="stepperDecrement(this)">-</button>
        <input value="0" name="dishIdQuantityMap[8]" type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" readonly />
        <button class="increment" type="button" onclick="stepperIncrement(this)">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="single-menu">

    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    <div class="menu-content">
      <h4>Dish number one<span class="price">25.00</span></h4>
      <p class="mb-0 text-color:red">DRINKS</p>
      <p class="menu-description">Custom description</p>
      <div class="myContainer m-1">
        <button class="decrement" type="button" onclick="stepperDecrement(this)">-</button>
        <input value="0" name="dishIdQuantityMap[6]" type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" readonly />
        <button class="increment" type="button" onclick="stepperIncrement(this)">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="single-menu">


    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    <div class="menu-content">
      <h4>Dish number two<span class="price">32.00</span></h4>
      <p class="mb-0 text-color:red">DRINKS</p>
      <p class="menu-description">Description</p>
      <div class="myContainer m-1">
        <button class="decrement" type="button" onclick="stepperDecrement(this)">-</button>
        <input value="0" name="dishIdQuantityMap[7]" type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" readonly />
        <button class="increment" type="button" onclick="stepperIncrement(this)">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="single-menu">


    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    <div class="menu-content">
      <h4>Dish number 4<span class="price">215.00</span></h4>
      <p class="mb-0 text-color:red">DRINKS</p>
      <p class="menu-description">Description</p>
      <div class="myContainer m-1">
        <button class="decrement" type="button" onclick="stepperDecrement(this)">-</button>
        <input value="0" name="dishIdQuantityMap[9]" type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" readonly />
        <button class="increment" type="button" onclick="stepperIncrement(this)">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="single-menu">

    <img src="/dish-images/1/49d.jpg" />

    <div class="menu-content">
      <h4>dsa2<span class="price">231.00</span></h4>
      <p class="mb-0 text-color:red">DRINKS</p>
      <p class="menu-description">dadsads</p>
      <div class="myContainer m-1">
        <button class="decrement" type="button" onclick="stepperDecrement(this)">-</button>
        <input value="0" name="dishIdQuantityMap[1]" type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" readonly />
        <button class="increment" type="button" onclick="stepperIncrement(this)">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="mb-3 text-center fw-bold col-8" style="font-size:1.5rem">
    <label for="address" class="form-label">Input your address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" required name="address" value="">
    <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-light mt-3 btn-lg">Confirm order</button>

  </div>

</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please paste code here. External links might break in future, and this question would be useless to people coming here.

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs _directly_ into your question, not just dumped onto an external platform (where from it could disappear at any time in the future.)

Comment: You are accessing menus.querySelector. You want menus[i].querySelector maybe

Comment: You’re iterating over `document.querySelectorAll('.single-menu')`, but then completely ignore the iteration variable `i` and attempt to access the collection as if it was an element. You got the right idea to iterate over the collection, so this looks like a typo. What do you think does the error try to tell you?

Comment: @SebastianSimon, yes, it was a solution, thank you!

Comment: Well, I’ve voted to close as _caused by a typo_, which still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const menus = document.querySelectorAll('.single-menu');` will [return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) as response. so `menus` is an array. You should use `menus[i].querySelector('.price').innerText` to access the node.

Also the element with class name `total-price` is not available.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
window.onload = function () {
  const totalPrice = calcOrder(); // calculate sum
  document.querySelector('.total-price').innerHTML = totalPrice; // put on page
}

// Calculate total sum
function calcOrder() {
  let result = 0;
  const menus = document.querySelectorAll('.single-menu');

  for (let i = 0; i < menus.length; i++) {
    const price = Number(menus[i].querySelector('.price').innerText);
    const qty = Number(menus[i].querySelector('input').value);
    result += price * qty;
  }

  return result;
}

function stepperDecrement(btn) {
  const inputEl = btn.nextElementSibling;
  const calcStep = inputEl.step;
  const newValue = parseInt(inputEl.value) - calcStep;
  if (newValue >= inputEl.min && newValue <= inputEl.max) {
    inputEl.value = newValue;
  }
  const totalPrice = calcOrder(); // calculate sum
  document.querySelector('.total-price').innerHTML = totalPrice; // выводим на странице
}

function stepperIncrement(btn) {
  const inputEl = btn.previousElementSibling;
  const calcStep = inputEl.step * 1;
  const newValue = parseInt(inputEl.value) + calcStep;
  if (newValue >= inputEl.min && newValue <= inputEl.max) {
    inputEl.value = newValue;
  }
  const totalPrice = calcOrder(); // calculate sum
  document.querySelector('.total-price').innerHTML = totalPrice; // выводим на странице
}
```

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.93), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.93)),
    url("../images/saveInPhotoshop.png") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* MENU */
.wrapper {
  color: white;

  width: 1200px;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.title h4 {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 36px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.title h4 span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.title h4:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #ff7720;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.single-menu {
  flex-basis: 580px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.single-menu:nth-child(5),
.single-menu:nth-child(6) {
  border-bottom: 0;
}

.single-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.single-menu:hover img {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.single-menu img {
  max-width: 180px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 3px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.single-menu h4 {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 22px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #333;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.single-menu h4 span {
  float: right;
  color: #ff7720;
  font-style: italic;
}

.filter-menu {
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 75px;
}

.filter-menu-desc {
  width: 460px;
}

.menu-description {
  width: 350px;
}

.price {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

/* Button */

.myContainer {
  width: 100px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 45px;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

input[type="number"] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  color: #302020;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

button {
  color: #ff7720;
  background-color: #d3d2d2;
  border: none;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.decrement {
  padding: 15px 5px 15px 25px;
  border-radius: 45px 0 0 45px;
}

.increment {
  padding: 15px 25px 15px 5px;
  border-radius: 0 45px 45px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">

  <div class="single-menu">

    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    <div class="menu-content">
      <h4>Dish number three<span class="price">15.00</span></h4>
      <p class="mb-0 text-color:red">DRINKS</p>
      <p class="menu-description">Description</p>
      <div class="myContainer m-1">
        <button class="decrement" type="button" onclick="stepperDecrement(this)">-</button>
        <input value="0" name="dishIdQuantityMap[8]" type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" readonly />
        <button class="increment" type="button" onclick="stepperIncrement(this)">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="single-menu">

    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    <div class="menu-content">
      <h4>Dish number one<span class="price">25.00</span></h4>
      <p class="mb-0 text-color:red">DRINKS</p>
      <p class="menu-description">Custom description</p>
      <div class="myContainer m-1">
        <button class="decrement" type="button" onclick="stepperDecrement(this)">-</button>
        <input value="0" name="dishIdQuantityMap[6]" type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" readonly />
        <button class="increment" type="button" onclick="stepperIncrement(this)">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="single-menu">


    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    <div class="menu-content">
      <h4>Dish number two<span class="price">32.00</span></h4>
      <p class="mb-0 text-color:red">DRINKS</p>
      <p class="menu-description">Description</p>
      <div class="myContainer m-1">
        <button class="decrement" type="button" onclick="stepperDecrement(this)">-</button>
        <input value="0" name="dishIdQuantityMap[7]" type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" readonly />
        <button class="increment" type="button" onclick="stepperIncrement(this)">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="single-menu">


    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
    <div class="menu-content">
      <h4>Dish number 4<span class="price">215.00</span></h4>
      <p class="mb-0 text-color:red">DRINKS</p>
      <p class="menu-description">Description</p>
      <div class="myContainer m-1">
        <button class="decrement" type="button" onclick="stepperDecrement(this)">-</button>
        <input value="0" name="dishIdQuantityMap[9]" type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" readonly />
        <button class="increment" type="button" onclick="stepperIncrement(this)">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="single-menu">

    <img src="/dish-images/1/49d.jpg" />

    <div class="menu-content">
      <h4>dsa2<span class="price">231.00</span></h4>
      <p class="mb-0 text-color:red">DRINKS</p>
      <p class="menu-description">dadsads</p>
      <div class="myContainer m-1">
        <button class="decrement" type="button" onclick="stepperDecrement(this)">-</button>
        <input value="0" name="dishIdQuantityMap[1]" type="number" min="0" max="100" step="1" readonly />
        <button class="increment" type="button" onclick="stepperIncrement(this)">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
  <p style="color: white" class="total-price"></p>
  <div class="mb-3 text-center fw-bold col-8" style="font-size:1.5rem">
    <label for="address" class="form-label">Input your address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" required name="address" value="">
    <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-light mt-3 btn-lg">Confirm order</button>

  </div>

</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer, could you please tell, why did minus button stopped working for all the code

Comment: Issues with `stepperDecrement` function, fixed and updated the answer.